# MIPS Assembly program that can read 2 integers from a text file and multiply them

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am working on a MIPS Assembly program in MARS that simply needs to be able to request a file name from the user, then multiply 2 integers within that text file. The integers must be on separate lines. The program must also output the results as "num1 * num2 = result". Here's what I have so far:

```
 .data
file:      .asciiz     "" #filename for input
prompt:     .asciiz     "Please enter the file name.\n"
buffer:     .asciiz      ""
newline: .asciiz "\n"
multi: .asciiz "*"
equals: .asciiz "="


.text
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt      #display prompt
syscall

li $v0, 8       #save entered string
la $a0, file    
li $a1, 200
syscall

li   $v0, 13       # system call for open file
la   $a0, file      # input file name
li   $a1, 0        # flag for reading
li   $a2, 0        # mode is ignored
syscall            # open a file 
move $s0, $v0      # save the file descriptor

# reading from file just opened

li   $v0, 14       # system call for reading from file
move $a0, $s0      # file descriptor 
la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer from which to read
li   $a2,  1000  # hardcoded buffer length
syscall            # read from file
move $s1, $v0           #$t0 = total number of bytes

#where I am stuck:
#
#
#
#




jal output
jal closeFile
li $v0, 10
syscall


output:#needs to have the form: integer1 * integer2 = result
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t5
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, multi
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t6
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, equals
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s7
syscall
jr $ra

closeFile:
    # Close the file 
    li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
    move $a0, $s0      # file descriptor to close
    syscall            # close file
jr $ra
```

Requesting the filename from the user and opening/reading the file are no problem. But I can't figure out how to store the 2 integers so I can perform the multiplication and save the result. I'm assuming a loop that goes character by character and stores in an array but I'm not sure how to do that in MIPS. I also looked into an atoi procedure and thought it may be useful? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is sort of funny situation, the MARS has syscall for entering integers from keyboard, but you can't redirect that to read from file (makes one to appreciate `fscanf` from C and the std in/out/file streams idea).

As far as I can tell, you have to write your own `atoi`, i.e. read the whole content of file into some bigger buffer, then read it character by character, and as long as those are digits, convert them (`tempvalue = tempvalue*10 + (char_digit-'0');`).

When you reach `<EOL>/<EOF>` or non digit character, the `tempvalue` is converted string into integer, store that somewhere and later use for ordinary integer arithmetic. Also probably check overflow situations.

So what I would do:

- read the file content to big-enough buffer - which you actually do, but you don't allocate memory for `buffer`. Doing `buffer: .asciiz ""` will reserve only single byte (the zero terminating the empty string). Use rather `.space 1000`. Try it in debugger, and check your `.data` memory after loading file content, how it overwritten your `newline` data.
- put extra zero terminator after the last byte of file (in case the file ends right after last digit) (make sure your buffer is big enough! i.e. read only 999 bytes if buffer is 1000).
- create procedure to convert string into integer, string at address `a0`, returns integer value in `v0` and address of next char in `a0`.
- create procedure to skip non-digit characters, address `a0`, end address `a1` (`buffer + 1000` to terminate when the file does not contain any digit character at all) (returns modified `a0` ... this is not proper MIPS calling convention, but makes it convenient to use for this particular case, I'm used to that, using my own custom-per-procedure calling rules, using official calling convention only when creating some public procedure .. but keep extensive comments then, specifying what the procedure does and where it expects inputs and where it returns outputs and what else is modified).
- then from main I would call the skip non-digit (check if the end of buffer was reached -> error input), read int, save `v0` somewhere (`s0` or memory), skip non-digit, check address, read int, save `v0` elsewhere (as second value).
- then you just use the two values in ordinary way.

further edit:

You can close the file right after reading it (just keep the read bytes amount somewhere). It's good practice to release resources as soon as you don't need them, unless you have specific reason not to. As you read whole file in one go, you can close it after and forget about it.

Comment: Ok thank you, could you elaborate just a little on the string2int procedure?

Comment: @alejandrocanto `tempvalue = tempvalue*10 + (char_digit-'0');` should be clear enough, try to decipher it, or ask which part is puzzling you. (maybe try on paper... let's say file contains `"123\n45<EOF>"`, that means the bytes content `31 32 33 0A 34 35` (the EOL may be different, depends on platform, like `0D` only, or `0D 0A` combination)

Comment: Quite a few things actually but I'm getting the hang of it and this is very helpful. Ok I'm translating this statement: tempvalue = tempvalue*10 + (char_digit-'0'); into MIPS and going from there.

Comment: @alejandrocanto the `'0'` is just different way to write value `48` (or `0x30 / 30h`, or `0b00110000` or ...), which is value of digit `0` in ASCII text encoding (check AS CII table to see how text characters are encoded into 8 bit values). So in above example of file content `31 32 33 0A 34 35` you read the first byte `0x31`, check that it is digit character `('0' <= 0x31 <= '9') == true`, subtract the 0x30 from it, you will get value `1`, and then temporary_value was zero, so result of that formula will be `1`. Next byte is `0x32` .. the same way you will end with `temp = 1 * 10 + 2 = 12`...

Comment: Ok thank you so much the logic is much more clear now. My file just contains "5\n5<EOF>" for simplicity and then I'll build on that. So basically when I call the str2int procedure I'm just reading the first byte (ascii '5') with:    `lb $t1, buffer($t0)` , confirming t1 is a decimal, and then subtracting '0' or 48 to get the decimal value of 5 and returning it in v0. Then skip the '\n' by calling something in main, and do the same thing for the second '5' and return it in v1? I know there's alot more details in between but I want to do this in pieces.

Comment: @alejandrocanto yes. Then (when this single digit conversion works and you debugged it) you extend that eating of decimals to be in a loop "till non-decimal detected", and "45" is not 4 + 5, but 4*10 + 5 .. etc.. each next digit makes the previous ones to be *10 (just like reading 123 from paper, once you realize there are 3 digits, you know the "1" is hundreds (*10*10  = *10^2), 2 is tens (*10 = *10^1) and 3 are ones (*1 = *10^0).

Comment: @alejandrocanto one thing I noticed now... "return it in v0. ... ... return it in v1." ... no, that's not how universal procedures work, you return the result each time in the same register, usually in v0 on MIPS to follow the calling convention. It's up to the caller to take v0, and store it somewhere, like `value_x .word 0` ...  `sw $v0, value_x`, or into one of the `$sX` register which should be preserved by any sub-call (also write yours in such way). It's easier to reuse than to write two times the same code, just returning value in v0 and v1.

Comment: I got the atoi loop down, but before that I had to do a procedure to remove the '\n' character from the file name caused by pressing enter, everything works great , thank you for help!

Comment: @alejandrocanto consider then to "accept" this answer if you find it sufficient (clicking the "check" icon on left side to answer top), it will both improve my "reputation" on this web site, and also make the question visibly "answered" when it shows in search results. :) Enjoy the assembly, it's beautifully logical and deterministic, once you will understand it's calculation-nature, it's actually very easy to learn. Yet hard to master (or more "tedious" than hard, to write anything more complex in assembly). ;)